# jqGrid : How to remove edit options?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have created a button and there I have attached the edit event in the following way -

```
$("#editButton").click(function() {
    var gr = jQuery("#gridTable").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');

    if (gr != null) {
        jQuery("#gridTable").jqGrid('editGridRow', gr, editParams);
    } else
        alert("Please Select Row");
});
```

But it is creating a problem for me. Here you see I'm setting the editParams again. I think this is the problem. Can I remove the existing editParams before adding them again?

Comment: What exactly problem you have?

Comment: Ok. I have a bundle of edit params which are necessary. And I want to give the user the edit capability both with default footer toolbar edit button and one of my custom html edit button. When I'm setting the custom edit button I need to set the edit parameters again, otherwise I'm not getting the exact behavior. But setting the edit params again created problems. Like each function is called twice - i have debugged that. So I think the better option will be remove the edit params from the jqgrid and then assign it back to the grid by the editButton click event.

Comment: the close function inside jquery.jqGrid.src.js calling twice and an error occured - "h is undefined". and then all on a sudden, all the edit, add, delete command does not work properly.

Comment: probably you need include more code which shows your implementation. Calling of the close function twice should be fixed. You should debug the error "h is undefined" (with respect of Developer Tools for example), look at the call stack and post in which line of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` it take place. You should additionally verify which JavaScript files and in which order there were loaded. **Probably including some JavaScript more as one time** could be the source of the problem.

Comment: @Oleg : You are always right. Yes. The javascript was adding the button onlclick function more than one, because i'm using ajax. so the problem being solved by adding the below code - $("#editButton").off() for each of my buttons. You can post your comment as an answer. I will accept it.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need include more code which shows your implementation. Calling of the close function twice should be fixed. You should debug the error "h is undefined" (with respect of Developer Tools for example), look at the call stack and post in which line of `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` it take place. You should additionally verify which JavaScript files and in which order there were loaded. **Probably including some JavaScript more as one time** or you made unneeded binding. It could be the source of the *original problem*.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need "editRow" method.

```
$("#editButton").click(function() {
    var gr = $.jqGrid.getGridParam('selrow');

    if (gr != null) {
        $.jqGrid.editRow(gr);
    } else {
        alert("Please Select Row");
    }
});
```

work for you?